# Why does :before only seem to work once in my code?

Tags: css

I am using :before to display webfont icons before menu items. For some reason :before is only working on one class and is completely ignoring the other class. If I change both classes on the two li's that should have icons before them to the working class name, the icon shows up.

Ideas?

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bigdmachine/erxjE/1/

Comment: Works over here.  Are you aware that you have `color: white;` in those class definitions?  White-on-white text is pretty hard for most people to read...

Comment: It works perfectly, the only issue is the 
        `color:white;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather update the CSS to;

```
nav#al-top-menu .log-out a:before, 
nav#al-top-menu .setting a:before {
     content: "X";
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 5px;    
     font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
     font-size: 14px;
     color: blue;
```

}

Comment: Wow....one of those WTF moments. Sometimes it takes someone else looking at it just to point something out so simple its stupid.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can create "free" pseudo-elements inside of an `<ul>` like that, the list should only contain list items.

Comment: Any content element (or non-replaced element) can create a pseudo-element. This includes `ul` and its `li` children.

Comment: I realize that now. And the only problem I see now is the white fg on white bg, if I remove that I can see both pseudo-elements.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I didn't downvote your answer by the way.